# How to add .click() event on form element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML code:

```
<body>
  <select multiple="multiple" id="imglist" class="image-picker show-html">
    <option><a href="http://placekitten.com/220/200" target="_blank">Cute Kitten 1</a></option>
    <option><a href="http://placekitten.com/180/200" target="_blank">Cute Kitten 1</a></option>
    <option><a href="http://placekitten.com/130/200" target="_blank">Cute Kitten 1</a></option>
  </select>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
.thumbnails {
  overflow: auto;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.thumbnails li {
  float: left;
}

.image-picker option {
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.image_picker_image {
  border-radius: 118px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  width: 50px !important;
}

ul.thumbnails.image_picker_selector li .thumbnail.selected {
  /* background: #fff !important; */
  border: 0px !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40) !important;
  opacity: 0.6 !important;
  background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather/96/circle-check-128.png') !important;
  background-size: contain !important;
}

ul.thumbnails.image_picker_selector li .thumbnail {
  border: 0px !important;
}

ul.thumbnails.image_picker_selector li .thumbnail.selected {
  background: #fff !important;
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
function imgpop() {
  var il, imga, imgatxt;
  il = document.getElementById('imglist').getElementsByTagName('option');
  for (i = 0; i < il.length; i++) {
    imga = il[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    imgatxt = imga.firstChild;
    imgatxt.nodeValue = imgatxt.nodeValue.replace(/ \(new window\)/, '');
    imga.onclick = function() {
        return popw(this);
      }
      //imga.onkeypress=function(){return popw(this);}
  }
}

function popw(o) {
  var newimg;
  if (o.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('img').length > 0) {
    o.parentNode.removeChild(o.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);

  } else {
    newimg = document.createElement('img');
    newimg.style.display = 'block';
    newimg.onclick = function() {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    };
    newimg.src = o.href;
    o.parentNode.appendChild(newimg)
  }
  return false;
}

if (document.getElementById && document.createTextNode) {
  window.onload = function() {
    imgpop();
  }
}
```

I want to generate image on click of option tag. And after clicking on option tag image should be hide. If I select first option tag, it should display image. and same with all the option tag.
My js file is not working for tags " select  option  /option /select" but if I provide image under " ul  li  /li  /ul" tag it start working.

Comment: for adding click event to any element dynamically, you can use `document.getElementById("id").addEventListener('click',function (){console.log('do somethings')})`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more the second part of your question? Do you want open a new image on a different browser Window?

Comment: To start off, your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `.click()` event on form element using jQuery as in the below example.

Documentation details from jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/click/

In can do the same in vanilla JavaScript (no jQuery) like this:

```
document.getElementById("imglist").addEventListener('click', function (){console.log('execute on click')});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#imglist').click(function(event) {
    alert(event.target.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="imglist" class="image-picker show-html">
  <option>Cute Kitten 1</option>
  <option>Cute Kitten 2</option>
  <option>Cute Kitten 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `<option>` element can only contain TextNodes

Comment: Can we generate new image on onclick() <option> tag ??

Comment: @BhaskarSaurabhVicky It's not possible, as <option> only supports text as properly commented by Kaiido.

Answer (score 0):

**you have try this**

```
var btn = document.createElement("form");
btn.addEventListener('click', keyFunction);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this, because input, select and textarea elements rendering depend from operation system, and I defenetly sure, that operation system DID NOT ALLOW use something except plain text inside of option. To do your task you should add onchange event, where you will do your logic.

Something like this

```
var select = document.getElement...
var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
switch(option.value){
  case '1':
  case 1:
    console.log(1)
    break;
}
```